# RecyclerView leaves residue on scroll

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a big activity (let's call it `BigActivity`) where I have a lot fragments inside. From `BigActivity` I start another one (let's call it `PainfulActivity`) with an `Intent` the usual way. I have a fragment living inside `PainfulActivity` and a `RecyclerView` in the fragment (let's call the fragment `PainfulFragment`).

In my `PainfulFragment` I make a network call and fetch my data. I have an adapter (let's call that `PainfulAdapter`) that I subclassed from `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
[image: a normal looking recyclerview]

And successfully wired up everything. Data is drawn on the screen and no problem until now. When I scroll `RecyclerView`, it leaves residue or glitch whatever you call it.

[image: glitching recyclerview residue]

I tried to populate my `PainfulFragment` in my `BigActivity` in one of the fragment containers, and everything works fine. So I know my fragment, adapter etc.. is working fine.

I tried to populate one of the fragments in `PainfulActivity` that normally lives in `BigActivity`, and I have the same problem, `RecyclerView` glitches again on scroll.

I was thinking perhaps it could be a memory problem, and observed the Profiler tool in Android Studio, however there is nothing unusual there neither.

Did anyone come across with such a problem?

Comment: Try adding a background to your recyclerview, it can be black color but don't keep it null

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!